# api - Get Facebook Post Data Using ID

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Everything is in the title. I've been looking for hours how to get a post data with his id. In php, javascript, fql or graph api, I do no care with which method. I would prefer in php, but i can adapt my work.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Query `https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID` with a valid access token.

Developer Documentation here:
developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/post

Comment: This API is now deprecated.

Comment: @Gfra54 - so you downvote something that was posted in 2012 as being deprecated - great job. I'm sure you can imagine that at the time of writing the situation was different.

Comment: well, it is marked has the answer for this problem, and yet it is deprecated. I tought this was the best way to show people that this solution is not good anymore. how should I do it ?

Comment: The latest version of the same API is here:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/post  Answer is still valid, thanks @Lix

Comment: Hi @stevenbranigan82 - thanks for the updated link. Did you know that you can suggest edits to other peoples posts? I'm fairly sure you can even edit my post above. Feel free to add your link - I think it'll still work without the version number in there :)